# In R how would you replace values in a matrix that have a certain condition with values from another vector?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix and a vector like this:

```
Matrix<-cbind(c(3,3,5,1),c(2,5,2,1))
Vector<-c(2,3,3,3)
```

I want to replace the Matrix elements that are >= the corresponding Vector value with the values in the Vector so that the Matrix would now look like this:

```
MatrixNew<-cbind(c(2,3,3,1),c(2,3,2,1))
```

What logic would achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought you had to use `apply(Matrix, \(x) pmin(x, Vector))`, but actually, you can just use `pmin()` directly on your `Matrix` because it will recycle the `Vector` to match the length.

```r
pmin(Matrix, Vector)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2    2
#> [2,]    3    3
#> [3,]    3    2
#> [4,]    1    1
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks very much!

Comment: Good work, elegant and efficient! Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [`pmin` method by @caldwellst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71062858/12158757) is the simplest one so far. Here is another option using `ifelse`

```
> ifelse(Matrix >= Vector, Vector, Matrix)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    3    3
[3,]    3    2
[4,]    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do it with `dplyr::mutate`.
It is interesting when you have to select a subset of variables.

```
library(dplyr)        
dd = structure(list(V1 = c(3, 3, 5, 1), ` V2` = c(2, 5, 2, 1), Condition = c(2, 
                3, 3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
dd %>% mutate(across(contains('V'), ~ifelse(.>=Condition, Condition,. )))
      V1  V2 Condition
    # 1  2   2         2
    # 2  3   3         3
    # 3  3   2         3
    # 4  1   1         3
```